# Data transformation in Azure Stream analytics

Tags: json, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

I am a little new to Azure.

I am building a `IoTHub` project on Azure.

I have setup the `IoTHub` to receive the messages from devices.

Also, I have setup the `Stream Analytics Job` to feed the received messages in `DocumentDB`.

Following is the JSON structure:

```
{
      "Location": "abc",
      "gateway": "def",
      "deviceId": "device1",
      "parameter1": value1,
      "parameter2": value2,
      "parameter3": value3
      "timestamp": time
}
```

Above is the data I am receiving per second from the device.

And, the data is getting inserted in `DocumentDB` if I don't do any transformation.

But, I want to transform the data as follows:

```
{
      "Location": "abc",
      "gateway": "def",
      "deviceId": "device1",
      "minute": 1,
      "data": { "parameter1": value1,
                "parameter2": value2,
                "parameter3": value3 },
              { "parameter1": value1,
                "parameter2": value2,
                "parameter3": value3 },....total 60 times for 60 seconds
}
```

Now, when a new minute starts the above JSON should be inserted into DocumentDB with updated first object of `data` parameter.

For the 2nd second there should not be any insert but only update the 2nd JSON object of `data` parameter and likewise for all remaining 58 seconds.

For, the next minute the `time` parameter will be updated as 2 or respectively.

Is there any way I can achieve this???

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's probably no easy way to achieve this with Stream Analytics, especially that DocumentDB is NoSQL.

Even there's a way to insert or update the db, it's probably NOT a wise thing to do each time after a new entry is added, think about you have millions of entries, each time it'll has to go over the whole records!

Comment: Why not do the reduce each time you connect to the db?